# How to have more get command in RESTFUL Webservice

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hi It is my first time to create Restful Webservice. I search the web but I didn't find the example how to have more than one get. In my assignment is about given the student information in the class. I need to have more than one get.

For example: 
1. The client  provides student name to get the student profile 
2. The client provides the student id to get the courses 
3. The client provides the student if to get the result

Would you have any example or link that I can study. Thanks.

Comment: Usually this is done with different url or different query string.

Comment: Can you post what you have so far? Potentially your controller class showing at least one GET? Also, is this C# or vb.net?

Comment: It's impossible for us to help you without knowing details about the technology/language/stack you are using. It sounds like it's ASP.NET MVC with Web API. Please edit/tag your question appropriately and show what you have tried so far, as @Michael suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Web API 2 (you have not provided enough details), this can be accomplished with [Attribute Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2):

```
[Route("api/Students/GetProfile")]
public StudentProfile GetProfile(string studentName)
{
    //Code here
    return studentProfile;
}

[Route("api/Students/GetCourses")]
public IEnumerable<Course> GetCourses(int studentId)
{
    //Code here
    return courseList;
}
```

I personally think you would be better served separating this into diffent APIs (e.g. Student API, Course API) but I do not want to question the design. You asked and I answered.